# Python: How to calculate the length of a range without creating the range?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, slice

I need to calculate the length of a range, but ideally without creating the range, (hopefully will be faster and use less memory. This is important, because this function will be called a lot). The length is used to set an extended slice.

Right now I have tried:

```
int_div = lambda n, d: (n + d // 2) // d

def range_len(start, stop, step):
    return int_div(stop - start, step)
```

But on some cases, such as range_len(9, 100, 3) it gives 30 when the correct answer is 31. I feel like this should be simple, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @FirebladeDan Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Are you saying I should do: range_len(start, stop, step) * step - 1 if step is greater than 0? (I assume you aren't, because that's wrong but that's what I understood it as)

Comment: why not xrange? What difference does it make?

Comment: For what it's worth, `range` in python3 implements a `__len__` that just calculates the number of terms (exactly what you're doing here). So calling `len` on python3's `range` is O(1).

Comment: @NightShadeQueen I'm using Python 2.7, but thanks.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen: that is very interesting, I thought python 3's `range` was exactly the same as Python 2's `xrange`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use this formula: `(end - start - 1) // step + 1`

```
def calc_length(start, end, step):
    return (end - start - 1) // step + 1

for i in range(start, end):
    calculated = calc_length(start, i, step)
    empirical = len(range(start, i, step))

    assert calculated == empirical, "{} {}".format(calculated, empirical)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, all solutions except for range() seem to be of similar speed and they all work, but I think this one is the simplest.

Comment: @Kytuzian: it fails for a negative step e.g., `range(10, 0, -1)`. You could use [this implementation instead](https://github.com/zed/lrange/blob/7bac49b3673ac632ae89c571d745c547854a54c3/lrange.py#L121-L134)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thank you. I have no negative steps in my program, but I will save that just in case.

Comment: @jfs How about simply `(abs(end - start) - 1) // abs(step) + 1`?

Answer (score 6):

In Python 2, you can use `xrange`. In Python 3, you can use `range`. In both, they return `xrange`/`range` objects instead of generating the whole list.

**Python 2**

```
return len(xrange(start, stop, step))
```

**Python 3**

```
return len(range(start, stop, step))
```

From the `xrange` help (in the Python 2 interpreter type `help(xrange)`):

```
class xrange(object)  
|  xrange([start,] stop[, step]) -> xrange object  
|  
|  Like range(), but instead of returning a list, returns an object that   
| generates the numbers in the range on demand.  For looping, this is  
|  slightly faster than range() and more memory efficient.
```

Or the `range` help in Python 3:

```
class range(object)  
 |  range(stop) -> range object  
 |  range(start, stop[, step]) -> range object  
 |  
 |  Return an object that produces a sequence of integers from start (inclusive)  
 |  to stop (exclusive) by step.  range(i, j) produces i, i+1, i+2, ..., j-1.  
 |  start defaults to 0, and stop is omitted!  range(4) produces 0, 1, 2, 3.  
 |  These are exactly the valid indices for a list of 4 elements.  
 |  When step is given, it specifies the increment (or decrement).
```

Creating `xrange`/`range` objects is faster and more memory efficient than creating the length of the associated lists.

Calculating the range from 0 to 1000000 using this method took my PC about 0.000004291534423828125 seconds.

Comment: I'd thought of this already, but it's I assumed the other solutions would be faster. Turns out they're all pretty similar (except for range, which is much much slower). Python 2.7 here

Comment: ## crisp solution ##

Answer (score 1):

It gives 30 because your integer division is rounding to the nearest integer when you want it to always round up. I don't know how fast it is, but I'd just use the math.ceil and float division.

Comment: Thanks, this works, all solutions except for range() seem to be of similar speed and they all work.

Answer (score 0):

I did this function using the Python C API and seems to work properly, I tested it with some range objects (works with any range).

```
static inline Py_ssize_t RangeSize(Py_ssize_t start, Py_ssize_t stop, Py_ssize_t step) {
    if ((step > 0 && start >= stop) || (step < 0 && start <= stop))
        return 0;
    return (Py_ssize_t) ((Py_ABS(stop - start) - 1) / Py_ABS(step)) + 1;
}
```

This is the python translation.

```
def range_size(start: int, stop: int, step: int) -> int:
    if (step > 0 and start >= stop) or (step < 0 and start <= stop):
        return 0
    return (abs(stop - start) - 1) // abs(step) + 1
```